# SQL Alchemy NULL identity key

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've defined the model's id field of the table like this:

```
id = Column(Integer(15, unsigned=True),
               nullable=False,
               server_default='0',
               primary_key=True,
               unique=True,
               autoincrement=True)
```

and altered the database(MySQL) table accordingly but still when I create the model
and try to commit it (Im using SQLalchemy 0.7.8)

```
m = MyModel(values without defining the id)
session.add(m)
session.commit()
```

I get this error

```
FlushError: Instance <MyModel at 0x4566990> has a NULL identity key. 
If this is an auto-generated value, check that the database table 
allows generation of new primary key values, and that the mapped 
Column object is configured to expect these generated values.  Ensure 
also that this flush() is not occurring at an inappropriate time, such    
as within a load() event.
```

Comment: Can you tell us which database you're using, which version of sqlalchemy you're using, and what is important to you about the result (i.e. must the pks start at 0, or are you ok with starting at 1)?

Comment: Im using SQLalchemy 0.7.8 and a MySQLdb. 
no the zero is not important.

Answer (score 2):

I use Postgres 13 and the type of ID is UUIT data type. I met the same issue.
I have solved it by applying server_default.

```
class TrafficLightController(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Tlc'
    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, server_default='uuid_generate_v4()')
    type_id = Column('type_id', UUID)
    title = Column('title', String(100))
    gps_x = Column('gps_x', Float)
    gps_y = Column('gps_y', Float)
    hardware_config = Column('hardware_config', JSONB)
    lcu_id = Column('lcu_id', UUID)
    signal_id = Column('signal_id', UUID)

    def __init__(self, type_id, title, gps_x, gps_y, hardware_config, lcu_id, signal_id):
        self.type_id = type_id
        self.title = title
        self.gps_x = gps_x
        self.gps_y = gps_y
        self.hardware_config = hardware_config
        self.lcu_id = lcu_id
        self.signal_id = signal_id

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dbschema = 'asudd'
    engine = create_engine(DB_CONNECTION_STR, connect_args={'options': '-    csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Base = declarative_base()
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session = Session()
    tlc_obj = TrafficLightController("b0322313-0995-40ac-889c-c65702e1841e", "test DK", 35, 45, "{}", None, None)
    session.add(tlc_obj)
```

Comment: This method gives me `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got <class 'uuid.UUID'>`. Anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the server_default value

Comment: The reason I was asking about the database backend being used is that you'll run into this problem with sqlite3, but not with, e.g., postgresql.  To just get rid of the issue altogether, you can simply drop the "server_default='0'" argument and it'll work in either database. I'm under the impression that, while sqlite supports autoincrementing primary keys with no problem, it's not able to generate values and return them before the flush.  One other thing worth noting is that setting primary_key=True also, by default, sets autoincrement=True and nullable=False, so you can drop those, too.

Comment: yeah you are right! It worked perfectly without the server_default

Comment: `unique` and `unsigned` is not necessary, too. It just makes your code more complicated. And I would suggest not to put a length restriction there and let the database handle the id column as default integer. So it could simply be: `id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)`.